# Is any way the function taking the values from the imported entries from the the Tk?

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl, tk-toolkit

So I want to run the `Tk()` and import there some values. Then these values will be checked from a function that will replacing the value in a particular cell in excel. This cell that matches with one imported entry. My challenge here is that the function works and replacing if I put manually the values inside the program BUT how can I make to read the values from the `Tk()` that I enter? I made a button so the function will be running after I have imported the values in the entry fields but still not. The "sntake" and "sngive" in the `replace()` function seems to not working... What am I missing?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
from xlutils.copy import copy
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
import openpyxl



app = Tk()

app.geometry("500x500")

app.title("S/N Management")

heading = Label(text="S/N Management",fg="black",bg="green",width="500",height="3",font="10")

heading.pack()

sngive_text = Label(text="S/N of the delivered ")
sntake_text = Label(text="S/N of the recieved  ")

sngive_text.place(x=15,y=80)
sntake_text.place(x=15,y=160)

sngive = StringVar()
sntake = StringVar()


sngive_entry = Entry(textvariable=sngive,width="30")
sntake_entry = Entry(textvariable=sntake,width="30")


sngive_entry.place(x=15,y=100)
sntake_entry.place(x=15,y=180)

def replace():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Tracker.xlsx')
    wb.sheetnames
    sheet = wb["serials"]
    amountOfRows = sheet.max_row
    amountOfColumns = sheet.max_column

    for i in range(amountOfColumns):
        for k in range(amountOfRows):
            cell = str(sheet[get_column_letter(i+1)+str(k+1)].value)
            if( str(cell) == sntake):
                newCell = sngive
                sheet[get_column_letter(i+1)+str(k+1)]=newCell

                wb.save('tracker_updated.xlsx')



button = Button(app,text="Submit Data",command=replace,width="30",height="2",bg="grey")

button.place(x=140,y=420)


mainloop()
```

Comment: Both `sntake` and `sngive` are `StringVar()`, you need to use `sntake.get()` and `sngive.get()` to get the content.

Comment: You dont even have to use `StringVar()`, just say `sngive_entry.get()` and so on.